# How to know for sure if an app has been removed from the play store?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-play

I'm running a script to scrape the play store but often I run into apps which are shown as not available when requested with `gl=us` (united states) but when the same app is requested via say `gl=fr` it shows up.

For example, this package name = `com.ns31.wimon`

With this urlm with `gl=us`, it shows as removed

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ns31.wimon&hl=en&gl=us
```

[image]

But same package with `gl=fr` works

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ns31.wimon&hl=en&gl=fr
```

[image]

So, how can I find out for sure if an app is deleted from the play store or just removed from one particular country?

Answer (score 0):

The app could be removed from one country only, usually this happened because of copyright violation and usually the copyright is in one country only or the country law is strict in that matter like USA.

Sometimes the law of a group of countries is causing the app to be removed from several countries (usually yo will see this in gabling games)

In other cases the developer is not targeting a specific countries, so they do not publish the app in those countries.

So you should check out all countries to be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Checking each package name I have in a massive list against each country will make the effort 200x bigger. Hence I'm looking for a sure shot method to check if the app is still on the play store and if yes, in which country.